# Onclick multiple hrefs with the same id

Tags: jquery

I am using a foreach to outut urls to useeguide articles, each value is unique for the links, but the id will be the same 'guideurl' when I click the first link in the foreach the jquery works, but on the second link it doesn't work nor does the jquery activate, here's part of my code:

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#guideurl').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo URL;?>help/viewguides/',
        data: 'guideurl=' + $("#guideurl").attr("value"),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#panel-body').html(msg);
        }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

and here's my href that is echoes in my foreach statement:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" value="<?php echo $guide->url; ?>" id="guideurl"><?php echo $guide->title; ?>
```

I'm not too sure how to bypass this.

Comment: ID attr should be unique in your document. if you're using id to find your element, jQuery returns only one element to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id should be unique in the page. You can't use an identity to find multiple elements in the page.

It's still possible to use the id attribute to locate the elements, but then you need to use it as an attribute, not an identity:

```
$('[id=guideurl]').click(function(){
```

When you get the value from the element, you should get the value from the element that was clicked, not use the selector to get it:

```
data: 'guideurl=' + $(this).attr("value"),
```

---

You should really use a class instead of an id for this. You don't have any benefit from it being an id.

Answer (score 0):

ID suppose to be unique, use class instead.
Address it with `$(".guideurl")`